# Sql request don't return row with the same name

Tags: sql

I need help with sql. Let's say I do have a table with columns id and name. I want to return the Name one time

```
id  name
1   A
2   A
3   C
4   A
5   A
6   B
```

i want my sql result to be like this

```
1   A
2   C
3   B
```

Thank you :)

Comment: SELECT name FROM [table] GROUP BY name

Comment: Did my answer get you what you are looking for? If yes, feel free to accept the answer so it could help others who come across with this type of doubts in future.

Comment: Is the `ID` in the result required, or is it just a row indicator? What version of SQL? In SQL Server you would use `ROW_NUMBER()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SELECT name FROM TableName GROUP BY name
```

**OR**

```
SELECT Distinct name FROM TableName
```

Result:

```
NAME
A
B
C
```

See Result in [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06c27/2).

**EDIT:**

To get the id as well, try this:

```
SELECT MIN(id) as id,name
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Distinct Name FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_names
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
```

Now you can do what ever you like with it.. 1 or more SELECT Columns you may Use JOIN to Join multiple tables and so on. I would recommend doing little research in the future, this is quite basic concept that is easily found with little effort.

Best of luck with your project.